# android beacon library transmit as ibeacon

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android, beacon

i want to transmit a beacon using android beacon library as an ibeacon.
i use the sample code from their site:

```
private void startIBeaconTransmit() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "beacon transmission started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1("44918498-F5B3-4A21-AC3D-7CD9B4EA8BEB")
            .setId2("1")
            .setId3("2")
            .setManufacturer(0x0000)
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
            .build();
    BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
            //.setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
    beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onStartSuccess: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onStartFailure: ");
        }
    });
}
```

i used different manufacturer codes and it didnt help
i scan with another phone with an app that i downloaded from the playstore, i see my beacon as altbeacon, how can i change it to an ibeacon?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close!

Use the second beacon layout shown in the question (the one that is commented out) except change it to start with `"m:2-3=0215`

Then  change the manufacturer code to use  `setManufacturer(0x004c)`